# Using a UICollectionView from a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell whose content is also a collection and I would like to use UICollectionView to display its content. Is this possible? How would I accomplish this? I  made the custom UICollectionViewCell also inheriting from UICollectionViewDataSource and define a UICollectionView internal property but things are not working as expected. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. Typically you would create a view controller which manages the inner collection view, and add the view of this view controller to the content view of the cell of the outer collection view.

You haven't given any description of you current attempts or problems encountered, so I can't offer much more than this.

Comment: Thanks!I ended up doing something close to your suggestion. When selecting a specific cell in the outer collection view, its view controller (which is the collection view's delegate) pushes a new view controller that manages the inner collection view. Something I didn't mention is that the difference between the two collection views is mainly in layout (grid versus horizontal) and few other things. For this reason I was thinking to achieve the same result by changing the layout at runtime but the layout transition wasn't as smooth as pushing a view controller.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of how this can be done. We have a storyboard with a standard UITableViewController, a custom UITableViewCell, and a separate freeform custom UIViewController.

```
// ContainerCell.h
@class CellContentViewController;
@interface ContainerCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) CellContentViewController*  contentViewController;
@end

// CellContentViewController.h
@interface CellContentViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel*   nameLabel;
@end

// CellContentViewController.m
@interface CellContentViewController ()    
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(UIButton*)sender;    
@end        
@implementation CellContentViewController           
- (void)didTapButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button for %@!", self.nameLabel.text);
}
@end

// MyTableViewController.m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* const kCellIdentifier = @"ContainerCell";
    ContainerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];        
    if (!cell.contentViewController)
    {
        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

        CellContentViewController* contentViewController= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CellContentViewController"];

        cell.contentViewController = contentViewController;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.contentViewController.view];
    }        
    cell.contentViewController.nameLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row];                
    return cell;
}
```

The result is that the custom view controller responds to the button taps. It is not the case that the view lifecycle methods are called as the view appears and disappears from the table.

I did this as a proof of concept, but for the project I'm working on I don't see any real advantage to having `CellContentViewController` be a view controller instead of just a custom view.

Comment: I add collectionView to tableViewCell but collection view only load for first row. if I scroll the tableview than collection view load data for second row and so on.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to add a container view to the UICollectionVIew prototype cell in the storyboard, as BrettThePark mentioned.

What you can do is create a separate view controller in the storyboard and add this programatically to the view in the UICollectionViewCell subclass you're using in your UICollectionView. This view controller can off course be a UICollectionViewController.

Example:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib 
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyUIViewController"];

    [self addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

Comment: Then you use a controller as a view. This works but can give you trouble when viewDidAppear and stuff is no longer called. You should add viewController as children and use methods like willMoveToParentView when you do so

Comment: I don't follow, doozMen. There is no View Controller per UICollectionViewCell. So, you cannot add the "MyUIViewController" controller to a corresponding view controller for the cell because there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`.

https://github.com/irfanlone/Collection-View-in-a-collection-view-cell

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand this isn't possible.

I tried doing it in storyboard and get the error:

"Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime"

Comment: I'm not surprised you can't do it in storyboards, but it is possible.

Answer (score -4):

Make your `UITableViewController` content as `Static`.

[image]

Comment: But... If you have to add a subview for each cell? (N cells)