# iOS Container View in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add another view controller inside a UITableView cell. The idea is that you tap the cell, and it expands to show more content--a messaging interface. It's important (I think) that this is controlled by a separate Messaging ViewController.

Expanding the cell and having views inside the cell expand with the proper constraints is actually very straightforward in Storyboards, so I tried to keep everything in storyboards by adding my new VC to the TableViewCell via a Container. That way I'd be able to add constraints on the container view, and pipe the content in from my Messaging VC.

Here's the error:

> Illegal Configuration: Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime.

Any way to get around this issue, or is there a way I can pipe the view from my viewcontroller into this tableviewcell and have it constrain to a configuration that I set in Storyboards? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like this is possible, but not via a storyboard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741951/using-a-uicollectionview-from-a-uicollectionviewcell

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same task and decided it this way:

**Step 1.** Create subclass `MyCell: UITableViewCell`.

**Step 2.** If you use `Self-Sizing Cells`, in InterfaceBuilder add UIView to MyCell, then add height constraint and constraints to all sides. This view needed for set height of cell.
If not, skip this step and use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

[image]
[image]

**Step 3.** In MyCell.h add outlet from view height constraint and controller property:

```
@interface MyCell: UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) MessagingVC *controller;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeight;

@end
```

**Step 4.** In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // adjust this for your structure 
    cell.controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MessagingVC" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];

    [self addChildViewController:cell.controller];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.controller.view];
    [cell.controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //  if you use Self-Sizing Cells
    cell.viewHeight.constant = 200; // set your constant or calculate it

    return cell;
}
```

**Step 5.** Add `didEndDisplayingCell` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MessagingVC class]])
         [((MyCell*)cell).controller removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: When using this, the tableview is not removed for some reason. You can see this in the Debug View Hierarchy, scroll up and down, and you will see an increasing number of tableviews including the containing cells. In order to fix this I had to remove the tableView of the controller in Step 5 first and then remove the controller from its parent view controller.

Answer (score 3):

Make your `UITableViewController` content as `Static`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag Container View into UITableVeiw in the storyboard. For example, you can drag it before prototype cell, and you will see your container's view controller before your prototype cells. By the way you can drag any UI element to table view. I'm not sure, how to deal with autolayout in the combination table view + container view, maybe you need to manually calculate / set constraints at the runtime. Will update my answer when I'll find the right solution about autolayout.

Comment: It's true you can add a container view into UITableView, it just won't compile.

Comment: @Joe you definitely could do this in the time when the original question was asked. I had released app that used this approach... Can't tell you about now, probably you're right. Not sure about downvote for an outdated answer, though.

Comment: The error of the original poster is the same as today - so no, the error was the same back then as today. They weren't asking if the container view *could* be put into a table view cell, they were asking how to get around the error. Granted, the title question is pretty weak. If you update your answer like you indicated in 2015, I'd be glad to remove the downvote and upvote it. I believe the answer is that you can put the container in the cell, but the error doesn't allow compilation for unknown reasons, like greg says in the original comment.

Answer (score -1):

Putting container views in table view cells is way too heavy. Table view cells should be lightweight so the user can scroll through them quickly. It's not necessary to put the entire view controller in each cell. The cell should just represent some of the data for that row.

When the user touches the cell you just use a normal segue to the messaging view controller. Its presentation will be automatic. Then create and specify an animationController to handle the transition to make it appear as though the message composition view was contained within the table view cell.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to present certain data in the table view cell to the user. So while you are correct, limiting the developer to only being able to implement tapping on the cell to reveal data isn't the solution. The solution is to use something more lightweight than a page view controller (i.e., collection view controller, perhaps?). Many apps embed collections of data in other collection objects.