# Adding subview to table view cell updates only on second reload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm adding a subview to my cell like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345629/ios-container-view-in-uitableviewcell) says.

But when I add it on cellForRowAtIndexPath:, the cell height is updated accordingly (as I modify the height constraint), but the subview only appears after I make a second reload data.

How can I make it update the cell just after I add the subview?

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

PastPartyTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HistoryPastPartyCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.mosaicView.frame.size.width, cell.mosaicView.frame.size.height)];
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.mosaicView addSubview:testView];

cell.cellHeightConstraint.constant = HistoryPastPartiesCellHeight + MosaicHeight;
cell.mosaicHeightConstraint.constant = MosaicHeight;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the subview inside of the `PastPartyTableViewCell` class?

Comment: try calling cell.layoutIfNeeded() after adding the view

Comment: @mattsson the behavior is the same

Comment: @KostasTsoleridis It didn't solve the issue...

Comment: Did you add the subviews to the `contentView` of your cell ?

Comment: @ChristophP. Yes, everything is showed correctly (including cell.mosaicView, in which I add the new subview), except for the newly created view.

Comment: `[cell.mosaicView addSubview:testView];` since `UITableViewCell` are reused, that's clearly not a good idea. Why don't you put that view management inside the code of `PastPartyTableViewCell`?

Comment: @Larme what do you mean?

Comment: Simply do the test: Put various cells, scroll, and then use Hierarchy Debug view of XCode, you should have some cells that have `testView` above `testView` about `testView`, etc.