# Hide or Show Static TableViewController Cells with a Segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am attempting to hide or show tableviewcontroller cells using a segmented control and a switch. The code below is not working and it will only print if I touch inside of the cell. I believe the touch causes the table to reload.

Code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

    switch(profileSegment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
        print("Seg Change")
        if cell == self.reviewsCell {
            return 0
        }
        tableView.reload()
        break

    case 1:
        print("Seg Change")
        if cell == self.watchCell {
            return 0
        }
        if cell == self.watchedCell {
            return 0
        }
        if cell == self.reviewsCell {
            return 500
        }
        tableView.reload()
        break

    default:
        break

    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)

}
```

Why is the tableview not reloading when the switch is made? Is there a more efficient way to achieve this other than changing the size to 0?

UPDATE:

I tried another route and made partial success. The switch works but only makes the cells appear blank. What would make the cells disappear completely?

CODE:

```
func segChange(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

switch(profileSegment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
        self.reviewCell.isHidden = true
        self.cell.isHidden = false
        tableView.reloadData()

        break

    case 1:
        self.reviewCell.isHidden = false
        self.cell.isHidden = true
        tableView.reloadData()

        break

    default:
        break

    }

}
```

UPDATE 2: If I use the code below the tableView will change the cells the first time I select the new segment index but the segment control does not change and becomes unresponsive. Why is the segment responding this way? If I fix this the question will be solved.

```
@objc func segChange() {

   tableView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

profileSegment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segChange), for: .valueChanged)


}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

    switch(profileSegment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
        if cell == self.reviewsCell {
            return 0
        }
        break

    case 1:
        if cell == self.watchCell {
            return 0
        }
        if cell == self.watchedCell {
            return 0
        }
        if cell == self.reviewsCell {
            return 500
        }
        break

    default:
        break

    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: You’re making life difficult for yourself by using static cells. It would be much easier to use a dynamic model and only display the cells you need

Comment: I’m using container views which only work with static cells.

Comment: You can manage to use container views inside a table view. see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38673948/1852207. But do you really need a container or just a re-usable cell? The latter is easier and more lightweight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my final update is to create `var selectedSegment = 0` at the top of the class.

Then add:

```
@objc func segChange(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    self.selectedSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex //Add this line of code

   tableView.reloadData()

}
```

This tells the segmented control to update its selected index. This was causing mine to not respond when I changed the index.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the cells is the problem

```
 if cell == self.reviewsCell { // it's wrong to keep cells ( like reviewsCell  ) as vars
```

you need to check the indexpaths

```
 if indexPath.row == 3 {   // hide cell at indexPath 3
```

Comment: This is not working. Nothing happens when I change the segment.

Comment: do you reload the table inside segment action ?

Comment: Yes. Only time I’ve gotten the table to react is by using self.cell.isHidden within the seg action with reload. It would hide the cells then not switch back or show the switch on the segment as if it was froze. I received no errors.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you reload the table view and set number of rows in section to 0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// if profileSegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
//  return 0 for this cell 
// }
// else {
//   return cell Height 
// }
}
```

and in your add target to your segmentedControl to change your flag and reload the table view.

```
self.segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: They are in the same section with the segmented control as the header

Comment: this is why we only setting the row to 0 not the section so don't worry this should work for you