# UICollectionView within a UICollectionViewCell (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to put a `UICollectionView` within each reusable `UICollectionViewCell`. The [Ash Furrow](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) method didn't work out too well for me, because using one `UICollectionViewController` class for the data source and delegate of two `UICollectionViews` does not work.

My latest approach is to put the view of a `UICollectionViewController` inside each cell, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14741951/2490299) and [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). However, when I go try to load the view, my app freezes. In the Xcode debug navigator, the CPU is at a constant 107% and the Memory approaches 1GB after a few seconds.

In this example, I am trying to get a `ThumbnailCollectionViewController` in each `MainCollectionViewControllerCell`. The only thing in each `ThumbnailCollectionViewControllerCell` is an image of size 50x50.

How is this done properly?

**In MainCollectionViewController**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    let thumbsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThumbnailColllection") as! ThumbnailCollectionViewController
    self.addChildViewController(thumbsViewController)
    thumbsViewController.view.frame = cell.bounds
    cell.addSubview(thumbsViewController.view)
    thumbsViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

**ThumbnailCollectionViewController**

```
let reuseIdentifier = "ThumbCell"
let thumbnails = ["red", "green", "blue"]

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return thumbnails.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    let cellImage = UIImage(named: thumbnails[indexPath.row])
    let cellImageView = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
    cellImageView.frame = cell.bounds
    cell.addSubview(cellImageView)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach to putting a `UICollectionView` inside each cell looks fine, but you are most likely seeing atrocious performance because you are mishandling cell reuse. You are adding a new collection view to the cell (and actually, a new image view to every thumbnail cell) EVERY time a new reusable cell is requested. If you scroll continuously, then cells will be dequeued that *already* have these subviews added, so you will end up with many many subviews under each cell.

Instead, add a means of checking whether a cell already has the subview or not, and only add it if it doesn't. Probably the best way is by using a custom cell subclass:

```
class ThumbnailCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var thumbnailViewController: ThumbnailCollectionViewController?
}
```

Back in your MainCollectionViewController:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThumbnailCollectionCell
    if cell.thumbnailViewController == nil {
        let thumbsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThumbnailColllection") as! ThumbnailCollectionViewController
        self.addChildViewController(thumbsViewController)
        thumbsViewController.view.frame = cell.bounds
        cell.addSubview(thumbsViewController.view)
        thumbsViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        cell.thumbnailViewController = thumbsViewController
    }
}
```

And again, something similar to prevent multiple `UIImageView`s being added to each thumbnail cell.

Comment: @Stuart,  I am not able to add "ThumbnailCollectionViewController". Can you help ?

Comment: @Stuart in my case i want to add different views to different cells...for example it can be a collection view, or chart or calendar view at run time...so which can be the best approach for me...nested collection view or using different tabs...or tableview with single column and different views inside it