# TableView nested in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a collectionView of TableViews so that each table will contain a "team" of players. (The idea is that the `Players` are equally sorted by their rating so that each team will be even at the end. Regardless) I'm having a little trouble populating the tables with the right players. The sorting/team-making code works fine, but I can't figure out how to reference the cell that each table is in from within the tableView dataSource method, which I need to populate the correct tables with their respective players. If you're confused, maybe the code below will clarify what I'm trying to do

```
class myCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK: Properties

    //These value are passed by the previous ViewController in PrepareForSegue
    var numberOfTeams = Int?() //2
    var team = Array<Array<Players>>() //The 2D array of Players which contains the already sorted teams

    //for right now this is my temporary solution. See below in TableView Data Source
    var collectionIndex = 0

    //MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if numberOfTeams != nil
            {return numberOfTeams!}
        else
            {return 2}
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell

        cell.teamTable.dataSource = self
        cell.teamTable.delegate = self
       //teamTable is a UITableView and is set as an Outlet in the CollectionViewCell. Here I'm just setting it 

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: TableView DataSource

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //add correct amount of rows
        return team[0].count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //reset for refresh so index won't go out of bounds of teams Array
        if collectionIndex == numberOfTeams
            {collectionIndex = 0
             print("reset")
        }
```

(This (just above) is where it fails. The view will load correctly, tables populating as they should. But if you scroll to the bottom of one of the tables, this method will be called and will refresh the table with the wrong data when you scroll up again. Code continued below)

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! teamTableViewCell
        cell.playerName.text = team[collectionIndex][indexPath.row].name
        //playerName is a UILabel set as an outlet in the teamTableViewCell class. also, The class Player has a property "name"

        //once all players are cycled through, add 1 to collectionIndex 
        if team[collectionIndex][indexPath.row] === team[collectionIndex].last
           {collectionIndex += 1}

        return cell
    }
}
```

As stated in the parenthesis above, the current implementation has problems and is only a temporary solution so I can continue working on other aspects of the code. What I need is to reference the collectionViewCell the tableView is in and change the line

`cell.playerName.text = team[collectionIndex][indexPath.row].name`

to

`cell.playerName.text = team[--"colletionViewCellIndexHere"--][indexPath.row].name`

but I don't know how to reference the collection cells indexPath.item or row from within the `tableview: CellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

I tried fooling around with `tableView.superView` but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do what you want is to actually give the responsibility of managing each table view to a separate view controller, `TeamViewController`. Each `TeamViewController` has its own `team` property, an array of players. When you create a collection view cell, add a new `TeamViewController` as a child view controller, and add its view as a subview of the cell. Just don't forget about cell reuse - you only want to add **one** `TeamViewController` to each cell.

Doing it like this will provide a better separation of logic, and will make managing your table views much simpler.

**Edit:**

An example that properly deals with cell reuse:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamsCell
    embedTeamInTeamsCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
}

func embedTeamInTeamsCell(cell: TeamsCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if cell.teamViewController?.team == teams[indexPath.item] {
        // The cell already has a team view controller, but it's for the wrong team – remove it
        detachTeamFromTeamsCell(cell)
    }

    if cell.teamViewController == nil {
        // The cell doesn't currently have a team view controller – create a new one and add it
        let teamVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TeamViewController") as! TeamViewController
        addChildViewController(teamVC)
        cell.addSubview(teamVC.view)
        // ... setup constraints on the newly added subview, or set frame
        teamVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        cell.teamViewController = teamVC
    }
}

func detachTeamFromTeamsCell(cell: TeamsCell) {
    if let teamVC = cell.teamViewController {
        teamVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        cell.teamViewController = nil
        teamVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        teamVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

In reality, it would probably be better to just reuse the current embedded `TeamViewController` instances rather than discarding them entirely when you need to change the embedded team in a cell. Then, simply changing the `team` property on `TeamViewController` should be enough to reconfigure that view controller to display the new team (perhaps you just need to call `tableView.reloadData` in the `team`'s `didSet` property observer – depends how you structure your class):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamsCell
    if cell.teamViewController == nil {
        // The cell doesn't currently have a team view controller – create a new one and add it
        let teamVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TeamViewController") as! TeamViewController
        addChildViewController(teamVC)
        cell.addSubview(teamVC.view)
        // ... setup constraints on the newly added subview, or set frame
        teamVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        cell.teamViewController = teamVC
    }

    cell.teamViewController!.team = teams[indexPath.item]
}
```

```
class TeamViewController: UITableViewController {
    //...

    var team: Team? {
        didSet { tableView.reloadData() }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a plan. I'm a bit of a rookie to swift and programming in general, is there anything special I need to do to set this new `TeamViewController` as a "child view controller"?  a small syntax   example of creating the child `TeamViewController` would definitely be helpful. (I assume `collectionView: numberOfItemsInSection` would be the best place to add the `TeamViewControllers` because (to my knowledge) it's only called once while setting up the view)

Comment: Sure, there are some containment methods on `UIViewController` that you need to call when adding/removing child view controllers. I wrote a brief example in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31959445/429427), otherwise you can check out the containment methods in [the `UIViewController` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:).

Comment: I'll work on it. Looks a bit advanced as I'm hardly a month into learning swift, but shouldn't be too rough to implement. Thanx for the help and the edit

Comment: No worries. Conceptually, view controller containment isn't the most simple topic for a beginner, but in practice it's actually not much work, and it's worth doing it right from the start. The View Controller Programming Guide for iOS is a great document from start to finish, but the [section on custom containers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12) might be particularly helpful to you.

Comment: Hey, so I was trying to use the method you gave and it's working fairly well but with one problem. The child subviews repeat when you scroll down the `collectionView`. The first three subview tables will populate correctly but scrolling further will just yield the same three over and over again. I followed the example you gave in the other answer, but still no luck. Do I need to remove the subviews when they're out of frame? I can post another question with the code if it helps

Comment: Yes, that happens because of cell reuse. You could either remove them entirely and re-add the correct child view controller, or ideally, just change the model associated with the currently embedded child view controller (change `teamViewController.team` to the correct team for that index path) and ensure your child refreshes itself. I've added more complete examples above that demonstrate both. I haven't tested it, so treat it more like pseudo-code!