# DIfferent Scroll direction for multiple sections of Collectionview in swift 2

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift2

I have an app with `UICollectionView` with 2 sections.My requirement is to have the first section should scroll in horizontal direction with one row only, while the second should scroll in vertical direction.I am working with Swift 2.1.

Please advice some solutions.

Comment: Add second UICollectionView (horizontal direction) into first section (vertical  direction), now the first UICollectionView  has data of section 2 and the second UICollectionView has data of section 1.

Comment: @Tim007 sorry I didnt get what u said.Can u please elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **UICollectionView** with 2 sections

Section 1: have only one **UICollectionViewCell** will contain a **UICollectionView**(horizontal direction) defined by its datasource.

Section 2: your current datasource.

You can check this one:

[UICollectionView within a UICollectionViewCell (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956495/uicollectionview-within-a-uicollectionviewcell-swift)

Comment: Thank you, got it.Anyway we have to use 2 collection views right?

Comment: @Neethu, yes, for now the best way to achieve this kind of scroll directions is to use Tim007 suggestion.